# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline using Packaged Build and Publish Profile

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-pipelines

I am trying to create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. We already have a functioning build pipeline that works well, it is able to package the build with VSBuild and publish it as an artifact. Then in the release pipeline I am using an IIS Deployment job (which includes IIS Manage and IIS Deploy tasks) and it gets that artifact to deploy.

The problem is that we already have a publish profile (.pubxml) that should take care of pretty much everything the IIS Deployment is doing (at least as far I as I understand it). So to me it seems I have two options that don't require me to refactor the project configuration itself.

1. I can try to mimic the settings on the IIS Deployment job to match our .pubxml as closely as possible and manually applying any changes that aren't doable through the task settings. Obviously this is not ideal as that would require us to update both when ever we make changes and it introduces a large chance of the pipeline breaking down over time.
2. I can scrap the idea of using IIS Deployment and just use a VSBuild task that uses arguments `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Staging`. This doesn't seem like best practices because it means my release pipeline isn't passing a build package to deploy, it is just creating a new one at each stage.

So is there a better option that would allow me to utilize the package I created with VSBuild and the .pubxml configuration together in a deploy? If that isn't possible then are either of my options the "correct" way to handle my situation or am I just missing another method of deployment I could use?

Thank you for any help or insight you can provide. Please let me know if there is any more information I can give that would be useful.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, how are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way I can achieve everything I wanted in this. The publish profiles are required for when we build the project so without making changes to how we configure those I need to build the project whenever I want to deploy. Ultimately I went with option #2. I essentially just copied most of the build tasks used in the testing pipeline and placed those in the release pipeline with a few modified commands to actually deploy the build once finished. It all seems to work just fine but still doesn't feel like best practices. If I am missing something please let me know and I will make updates as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using publish settings file (**`*.publishsettings`**) for your IIS deployment.

> A publish settings file (*.publishsettings) is different than a publishing profile (*.pubxml) created in Visual Studio. A publish settings file is created by IIS or Azure App Service, or it can be manually created, and then it can be imported into Visual Studio.

To view more details, you can see:

- [**Publish an application to IIS by importing publish settings in Visual Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019)
- [**Deploy your app to a folder, IIS, Azure, or another destination**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components-resources?view=vs-2019#web-server-iis)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, after looking into it I don't think it will satisfy our needs. First we were really trying to avoid changing any existing configuration locally. Ideally the change would entirely be in the pipeline. Also our publish profile has a decent amount of functionality that doesn't seem to be available in publish settings without significant reworking. After doing more research it seems like option #2 may be our best bet, but I'll update this thread once I actually finish everything.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, looks like, you can import the previously configured any publishing profile for deployment. The following articles may be helpful to you: [**Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml) for ASP.NET Core app deployment**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [**Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thank you, I'll check those out.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, how are things going? Any update, feel free to tell us.

Comment: Those articles were definitely helpful in setting up the publish profiles on the pipeline. Unfortunately I ran into an unrelated Agent issue during the deploy that has slowed my progress. I'll make sure to update the thread once I get a more stable solution.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, please go ahead. And if there is anything we can help, feel free to tell us.